# Is a double pole, double throw switch correct for my spa cover motor?

Tags: wiring

I have a pool cover motor with a wireless switch that went bad. I want to connect a manual switch for the off season until we replace the cover. I've been trying to connect a DPDT switch but can't figure out the correct connectivity and don't have much info on the motor.

The motor: Cover Pools Model V0731A820, 115 AC

White ----- L1
Blue 
Red
Black ------L2
Yellow

Motor states to reverse interchange Yellow and Blue.

should I be using a DPDT switch and any suggestions on how to wiring this up?

Thanks for the help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fudEiy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Turn power Off before reversing direction.

Normally a 3 position DPDT switch with Center Off is preferred.

Here is a Mom-Off-Mom rocker switch 20A 120V
https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/cw-industries/GRB260K101BBNN/CW129-ND/2349709

Comment: WoW! thanks so much for the help. I have a DPDT from Garnder Bender. Can you I ask you for real specific connections to/from the motor for a novice like me?

Comment: Can't you see the wire colours are the real connections.  Just cut and wire it like this.